Why are there some shadowy lines here?
This is my rendered result and there are some lines. What is the cause of this?



I can answer your question what is causing this, but unfortunately I have no solution how you can get rid of this while maintaining the overall look you are going for. First of all, the radius of the dark spherical contour is determined by the Blend value of the Layer Weight node, a smaller value makes it larger and vice versa. And the bright larger outline (especially visible below the plane) is the size of the sphere: layer weight influence.

You can remove the Transparent BSDF in the Plane material, this will get rid of the dark contour from the Layer Weight and you will no longer see the bright outline of the sphere below the Plane. But when the accretion disk is no longer transparent it will have other unwanted effects as you can see: no transparency in accretion disk. Apart from the black streaks accluding the inner circle, the outline of the sphere is still slightly visible in the transition from the border to the background.

will switching the render engine to cycle make it possible?

Maybe. I've actually not tried to do it, because when I switched to Cycles the whole refraction effect looks completely different than in EEVEE, so first of all you would have to find a way to get something similar looking in Cycles.

Yea, you are right.

I tried a little bit but Cycles still looks very different... the result I achieved by setting the Power node's Exponent in the sphere shader instead of -3 to +10. Not the best result but there I could do something about the dark area. As you can see in the following image, on the left there is a clear dark outline where the original sphere is. On th eright it is gone. I achieved this by disabling Clamping for Indirect Light in the Light Paths settings in the Scene Properties. Unfortunately this does not exist for EEVEE. disabled clamping
